# my website does not get visited by google bots?

Tags: web, googlebot, bingbot

I am trying to understand why my website does not get visited my google bots.

http://www.nateiss.com/

I used Site-Analyser to analyse my site - you can see the website report.
http://www.site-analyzer.com/en/audit/http://www.nateiss.com#report-page-6

What Should I do to make majors bots: google, yahoo, bing to visit it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I was facing before 1 year ago. Because my website http://www.silkyquote.com/ was not listed in google. But now `googlebot` daily visiting my website.

1. If your website or blog is new than `googlebot` takes time to crawl your website.
2. If your website is not update regularly than `googlebot` not visit your site regularly.

So, update your website daily. In shot time `googlebot` will crawling your site.